# Как в С скопировать папку со всеми файлами и перенести по указанному path

Tags: c++, c, файлы, файловая-система

Мне необходимо скопировать папку со всеми файлами и перенести по указанному мною path, как это сделать? Различные MoveFile, CopyFile не подходят, так как они копируют только один файл, а мне нужно скопировать целиком папку со всем содержимым.

Comment: указывайте ОС .

Comment: я использую windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ну раз вы тут упоминаете WinAPI, то используйте `WinExec`

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec

сформируйте команду (т.е. создайте строку с указанием команды и старого и нового места папки), которой из консоли бы копировали папку со всеми файлами, и вызовите ее :)

2. использовать `MoveFile`, `CopyFile` тоже можно, просто для начала найдите все файлы в выбранной папке через `FindFileNext

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea

3. вот тут умных мыслей набросали по данному вопросу

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725115/on-windows-is-there-an-interface-for-copying-folders

Comment: совет использовать WinExec из 16 битной эры откровенно трешовый

Answer (score 3):

Раз у вас тэг С++, то все просто:

```
std::filesystem::copy("dir1","dir2");
```

Подробнее о том, какие параметры можно передавать этой функции, смотрите [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy).

Comment: вы не указали что должен быть `c++17`

Comment: @Lofectr или boost::filesystem

Comment: @Lofectr Чай, не в XX веке живем...

Comment: @Harry во многих компиляторах по умолчанию `с++11`. И не все знают про стандарты и тд и тп. Так что лучше было бы сказать